# Prestashop target error validation in w3c validator

Tags: html, prestashop, w3c-validation

I'm trying to help my girlfriend with eshop, so I was trying to repair all the errors on her prestashop installation. Unfortunately, I'm stuck here too because I can't repair last one. It's about target property in anchors from one module. This is the page: ciapkydede.sk

and here is W3C validation: https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=ciapkydede.sk&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Please, can someone help me solve this problem or at least give me some direction where to look? I'll be even thankful for advice about debugging.

Answer (score 0):

The target attribute is not valid in XTHML 1.1

You can remove the `target="_self"` attribute since the default value for `target` is `_self` or you can continue to use it and ignore the validator error since it is supported in all browsers and is valid in HTML5.

Comment: That´s what i know too, the question is where to remove it? Because i want to put him away, but i can´t find that line where to do that. So i was looking for some advice how to find him...